# Is there a way to add a 'Misc' into an integer column when there is missing data in that column or should I stick to nulls?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Is there a way to add a 'Misc' into an integer column when there is missing data in that column or should I just allow nulls for that column?

ex.

Table:

```
ItemNo. | ItemName|
-----------------------
1       | Axe
-----------------------
2       | Shovel
-----------------------
Misc    | Rake
-----------------------
3       | Plow
-----------------------
```

OR

```
ItemNo. | ItemName|
-----------------------
1       | Axe
-----------------------
2       | Shovel
-----------------------
        | Rake
-----------------------
3       | Plow
-----------------------
```

Comment: Keep it to Null. Displaying Misc should be in the UI logic, not the database. Or do it in your select statement if you really need to.

Comment: Following on, something like the DGV provides the ability to display something else for `DBNull`

Comment: ah good thinking, thanks.

Comment: @the_lotus actually new problem, I can't make the column nullable because it's being used as a Key. How should I keep it as a key but somehow allow random/misc info..? Have it be entered as something like 99999?

Comment: If it's a key column, how did the nulls get there in the first place?

Comment: @DanBracuk it gets added onto the table with an insert but the inserted information doesn't have data on the column that is a foreign key.

Comment: maybe I simply need to make the column not a FK...?

Comment: Depends on the database but you can have null as foreign key. An other option is to have a Misc item in the other table and link to that row.